# Wird das Wort "Werktätige" heutzutage noch verwendet? Was sind alternative Begriffe?

Tags: noun, synonym, word-usage, word-choice

Der Begriff „Werktätige“ bezeichnet wohl Menschen, die ein Einkommen aus nicht selbstständiger Arbeit beziehen. Wie verbreitet ist dieser Begriff und (wo) wird er heute noch benutzt?

Wie bezeichnet man heutzutage Menschen, die durch Lohnarbeit ihren Unterhalt bestreiten? „Angestellte“ und „Arbeiter“ fassen jeweils nicht alle Personen zusammen. Gibt es entsprechende Alternativen oder Synonyme?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Der Begriff "Werktätige" wird heutzutage eher selten verwendet. In der ehemaligen DDR war "Werktätige" *die* Bezeichnung für die arbeitende Bevölkerung und war ideologisch geprägt.

**Arbeitnehmer** dürfte die geeignetste und gängigste Alternative sein. Dieser Begriff umfasst Arbeiter und Angestellte, nicht aber Selbstständige oder Freiberufler.

Weitere Alternativbegriffe sind z.B. Berufstätige, Erwerbstätige oder Beschäftigte. Diese beinhalten in Gegensatz zu Arbeitnehmern allerdings auch selbstständig oder freiberuflich tätige Personen.

Comment: bei Arbeitnehmer ist stört mich das "nehmer" - man produziert ja normalerweise etwas und stellt seine Arbeitskraft jemandem zur Verfügung

Comment: Das Wort ist aber im Prinzip ganz logisch, auch als Gegensatz zum Arbeitgeber: Der Arbeitnehmer nimmt die Arbeit an, die ein Arbeitgeber anbietet. Das hat nichts damit zu tun, dass dabei etwas produziert wird.

Comment: @musiKk http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbeitnehmer#Kritik_am_Begriff

Comment: @musiKk ich finde kaum ein anderes Wortpaar dessen Mitglieder man so gut austauschen könnte!